# 括弧[]で囲まれない全ての部分文字列を置換したい

Tags: ruby

1. かっこ`[]`で囲まれた文字以外を取得
2. 取得した文字列を加工
3. 加工した文字列に置き換える

例

`"[ほげ]あいうえお[ふが]かきくけこ"`

↓

`"[ほげ]<あいうえお>[ふが]<かきくけこ>"`

このような処理をrubyで行いたいのですがどうやったらよいのでしょうか。
どの様な関数を使って処理するのかまったくイメージがつかめません・・・

Comment: 質問の題名を改良してください。不適切です

Comment: タイトルを目的ベースに書き換えました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

こんな感じでどうでしょうか。
[ ]で囲まれる部分とそうでない部分をマッチさせて、
[で始まるものはそのまま、そうで無いものは<>で囲みます。

```
p "[ほげ]あいうえお[ふが]かきくけこ".gsub(/((\[.+?\])|(?!\[)([^\[\]]+))/){ $1[0] =='[' ? $1 : '<' + $1 + '>' }#/((\[[^\]]+\])|([^\[\]]+))/
```

Comment: すばらしい。頑張って読みといてみます!!!ありがとうごじあます。

Comment: ([で始まって]で終わる文字列) | ([で始まらない[]ではない文字列)です。

Comment: なるほど!!理解できました。両方とも取得して後で判定するなんて思いつかなかったので、感動しています。本当にありがとうございます。後ほどベストアンサーとさせていただきます。

Comment: 正規表現の前半は `/((\[[^\]]+\])/` （ `[` で始まり `]` ではない1文字以上の文字列が続き `]` で終わる）でもいいですね。 `(?!\[)` が上手く使えていて憧れます。

Answer (score 3):

`<>`で囲む文字列は、

- 行頭か`]`の後から始まる
- `[`を含まない文字列
- `[`か行末の前で終わる

という特徴があるので、それを正規表現で表すと次のようになります

```
puts "[ほげ]あいうえお[ふが]かきくけこ".gsub(/(?<=^|\])([^\[]+)(?=\[|$)/, '<\1>')
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML/XML同様、入れ子になる可能性のある文章に正規表現を使ってはダメです。

```
orig = "[ほげ]あいうえお[ふが]かきくけこ"

nest = 0
ar = []
orig.split(/\b/).each do |token|
    change_nest = token === '[' ?  1
                : token === ']' ? -1 
                :                  0;

    nest += change_nest;

    if change_nest != 0 then
        ar.push(token)
        next
    end

    if nest != 0 then
        ar.push(token)
        next
    end

    ar.push("<#{token}>")
end

p ar.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

全部正規表現で対応しようと思うと正規表現が複雑になって保守性が悪くなりそうな気がしました。
なので、"[ほげ]"のような部分だけを抜き出す正規表現を使い、あとはRuby側で文字列処理を行うようにしてみました。

```
def surround_with_angle_brackets(string)
  regex = /(\[.*?\])/
  words = string.split(regex)
  words.reject(&:empty?).map{|w| w =~ regex ? w : "<#{w}>" }.join
end
```

あと、テストコードも書いて質問以外のパターンでも動作確認しています。

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class TestSurroundWithAngleBrackets < Minitest::Test
  def surround_with_angle_brackets(string)
    regex = /(\[.*?\])/
    words = string.split(regex)
    words.reject(&:empty?).map{|w| w =~ regex ? w : "<#{w}>" }.join
  end

  def test_surround_with_angle_brackets
    # 質問と同じ
    assert_equal '[ほげ]<あいうえお>[ふが]<かきくけこ>', surround_with_angle_brackets('[ほげ]あいうえお[ふが]かきくけこ')
    # []が連続する場合
    assert_equal '[ほげ]<あいうえお>[ふが][ふが]<かきくけこ>', surround_with_angle_brackets('[ほげ]あいうえお[ふが][ふが]かきくけこ')
    # []以外で始まり、[]で終わる場合
    assert_equal '<あいうえお>[ふが]<かきくけこ>[ほげ]', surround_with_angle_brackets('あいうえお[ふが]かきくけこ[ほげ]')
    # []がない場合
    assert_equal '<あいうえお>', surround_with_angle_brackets('あいうえお')
    # すべて[]の場合
    assert_equal '[ほげ][ふが]', surround_with_angle_brackets('[ほげ][ふが]')
    # 文字列が空の場合
    assert_equal '', surround_with_angle_brackets('')
  end
end
```

よかったら参考にしてみてください。

Answer (score 0):

私も挑戦してみました。

```
def f(t)
  t.gsub(/(^|\])([^\]]+?)(\[|$)/,'\1<\2>\3')
end

puts f("[ほげ]あいうえお[ふが]かきくけこ")
puts f("あいうえお[ほげ]かきくけこ[ふが]")
puts f("[ほげ]あいうえおかきくけこ[ふが]")
puts f("あいうえお[ほげ][ふが]かきくけこ")
```